# How to connect to Oracle using SQLPLUS | Oracle Instant Client | ORA-12545

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Connecting successfully using SQL Developer but when i use sqlplus in Oracle Instant Client then i get following issues

Method 1:

```
[integrator@a-esb-app01 instantclient_19_8]$ ./sqlplus EGOINT@139.138.267.202:1521:EPROD

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Dec 22 18:14:36 2020
Version 19.8.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist


Enter user-name: egoint
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified
```

Method 2:

```
[integrator@a-esb-app01 instantclient_19_8]$ ./sqlplus EGOINT@139.138.267.202:1521/EPROD

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Dec 22 18:18:13 2020
Version 19.8.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor
```

Not Sure which of above is correct method and what is issue with connection string or any changes required on server side?

Note: I am able to connect another Oracle Server successfully. So no issue with InstantClient

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ape.htm

Comment: When you connect from SQL Developer do you supply a SID or a service name? The first JDBC syntax uses a SID, which isn't supported by Easy Connect. The second uses a service name (the `/EPROD` part). I'm guessing that for the other servers you can connect to the SID and service name are the same, but they aren't for the problematic one. Run `lsnrctl services` on the DB server machine to get the valid values, or ask your DBA.

Comment: @AlexPoole: I do not have access to oracle Server. It is client which i installed on linux and able to connect it using a long string i mentioned in my answer and it is SID

Comment: Right, so ask your DBA for the service name to use. Changes aren't required on the server side, you just need to know how it is currently configured. Or if you still want to use the SID then use the long connection string as you've shown in your  answer, or set up a local `tnsnames.ora` file to give that connection info a TNS alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed using following:

```
./sqlplus egoint/egoint@(description=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=139.138.267.202)(port=1521))(connect_data=(sid=EPROD)))
```

Comment: Typically you define an **alias** for this complicated string. Usually this is done in the `tnsnames.ora` file. Google for it, you should find many examples.

Comment: You really need to find the (or one) service name and start using that.  Connecting via a service will let you get access to some Oracle high-availability features.